# pandas to_csv arguments float_format and decimal not working for index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, decimal-point

I have the following snippet to export my data as a csv file:

```py
rpm = [0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]

df = pd.DataFrame(get_some_data_from_somwhere(), index=rpm)

with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:
    data.to_csv(f, index=True, header=True, decimal=',', sep=' ', float_format='%.3f')
```

It creates a csv-file that has the following format:

```
rpm cooling_inner heating_inner cooling_outlet heating_outlet
0.25 303,317 323,372 302,384 324,332
```

However, I expected having three decimal digits and a comma as decimal sign on my index column, like shown here:

```
rpm cooling_inner heating_inner cooling_outlet heating_outlet
0,250 303,317 323,372 302,384 324,332
```

So it seems that the `index` and `decimal` sign options are not applied to the index column when exporting dataframes to csv-files using the `.to_csv` command.

How could I achieve this behaviour since the `index` option is set `True` and all values (with exception to the index column) have the right format and decimal sign?

Do I have to handle the index column somehow separately?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would rewrite your two bottom lines:

```
with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:
    data.to_csv(f, index=True, header=True, decimal=',', sep=' ', float_format='%.3f')
```

Into

```
data.reset_index().to_csv('foo.csv', index=False, header=True, decimal=',', sep=' ', float_format='%.3f')
```

This is a bit of a workaround, but as you have noticed, the keyword arguments `decimal=` and `float_format=` only work on **data** columns, not on the index.

What I do instead is to put the index into the dataframe with `reset_index` and then I tell `to_csv(index=False` not to save the index to the file (since it is now in the data).

Also, opening a file stream yourself (`with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:`) is better left to pandas, which does this by itself when you just give it a string `'foo.csv'` as first argument.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of pandas (e.g. 1.5.3), index is formatted with `float_format` along with the values in the columns. So the following does precisely what OP desires:

```py
df.to_csv('foo.csv', sep=' ', decimal=',', float_format='%.3f')
```

If you came to this post looking for a way to get the old behavior (where the index is not formatted the same as the values in the columns), `round()` could be used before dumping to a csv file.

```py
df.round(3).to_csv('foo.csv', sep=' ', decimal=',')
```